# Change theme color by SASS variable

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I am working on a theme and I put a SASS `var $main_color: #09f` for example. So I have a choose color button in my theme. Now I created other color variables. How can I select them by jQuery and change the main color?

for example :

```
$main_color: #09f;
$color_1: #093;
$color_2: #f00;
$color_4: #ddd;
```

Comment: SASS is precompiled, so you cannot change any of its variables at run time. A better solution would be to base the theme on a class on the `body` and then add/remove that class as needed

Comment: ok. :( .. I just built all the theme on that var .. that sassy is incompletely useful ... thank you so much. I will try your idea